# html2canvas resize image and download

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2canvas, todataurl

I have the following code below, and I need this image that is generated, to be generated in 1080x1080, how can I proceed, and after that the image is downloaded with 1080x1080px, how can I increase my code to make it happen?
Currently it generates the canvas with 537x537px and after that it downloads in that size, but I want it to be done in 1080x1080 and in excellent screenshot quality

```
<div class="formulario">
    <form id="geradorPublicacao" name="geradorPublicacao">
        <label for="frase">Escreva aqui o que é liberdade para você e gere seu próprio pensamento para compartilhar nas
            redes sociais:</label>
        <textarea id="input-frase" name="frase" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="150"></textarea>

        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="input-nome" placeholder="Seu nome" required>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="nome@email.com" required>

        <label for="select">Você já conhece a Sankhya?</label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="Sim, sou colaborador">Sim, sou colaborador(a)</option>
            <option value="Sim, sou cliente">Sim, sou cliente</option>
            <option value="Não, mas quero conhecer">Não, mas quero conhecer</option>
        </select>

        <button id="btn-Preview-Image" type="submit">Criar publicação</button>
    </form>

    <div id="teste-imagem">
        <span id="input-nome"></span>
        <span id="input-frase"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="previewImage" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>

<script src="https://www.sankhya.com.br/wp-content/themes/understrap-child/html2canvas.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"-->
<!--    integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="-->
<!--    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->

<script>

jQuery(function($){

    var element = $("#teste-imagem"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable
    
    $('#geradorPublicacao').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var inputNome = $('#input-nome').val();
        var inputFrase = $('#input-frase').val();
        var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;
        

        $("#conteudo-nome").html(inputNome);
        $("#conteudo-frase").html(inputFrase);

        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
            }
        });
        // return false;
    })

    // $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function (e) {
    //     e.preventDefault();

    // });
    
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function (e) {
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "liberdade.png",).attr("href", newData);
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas has a set of options. See http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/

Currently the only option you are setting is the function to be run when the canvas has completed being rendered. You are not setting the width or height or giving it a canvas so it's creating one for you.

You could try adding height and width to the set of options:

```
html2canvas(element, { width: 1080, height: 1080,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
        getCanvas = canvas;
    }
```

Comment: Hello how are you? I added the options only that it returns an empty screenshot, would it be related to the size of the div? Because my div I make the screenshot is less than 1080x1080